# Run javascript on dynamically loaded content for ajax based website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I an currently designing a ajax based navigation website. The problem I encountered is when I try to run jquery on dynamically loaded content it doesn't work.

Here is what I did:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Dynamic Content</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="http://localhost/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">
            <ul class="list">
                <li>One</li>
                <li>Two</li>
                <li>Three</li>
                <li>Four</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $('.list').greenify();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**2.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Testing Dynamic Content</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="http://localhost/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="content">
            <span id="hello">Content</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
    $('#hello').on('click',function(){
        $('.main').load('index.html .content');
        $('.list').greenify();
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**style.css**

```
.list{
    color:#f00;
}
```

**main.js**

```
$.fn.greenify = function() {
    this.css( "color", "red" );
};
```

The problem is in the **$('list').greenify();**. When I load content of index.html on 2.html using .load() the content loads in red color as defined in css. When I run $('list').greenify() on this loaded content it doesn't works.

**How can I run mak this happen to run JavaScript on dynamically loaded content?**

I need to do this to make a slideshow run on dynamically loaded webpage. And slideshow is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You should bind the events like this then only your script will affect on dynamic DOM elements

```
 $('body').on('click','#hello',function(){
        $('.main').load('index.html .content');
        $('.list').greenify();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

issue is your code run before your page successfully loaded, move your code to document ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.list').greenify();
})
```

and jQuery load is async you need to run your javascript in success function

```
$('.main').load('index.html .content', function() {
    //will execute when load successfully
    $('.list').greenify();
});
```